# Delete pandas DataFrame rows with content from array

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have a big DataFrame (~1 Milion lines) and i need to delete some rows based on the unique identifier Trade_Id.  I have the content of this rows (45000 on my test database) on another DataFrame variable called tib. My approach is this one

```
lentib=len(tib)
for i in range(0,lentib,1): # VERY SLOW
    dat=dat[dat.Trade_Id!=tib.Trade_Id[i]]
```

But the problem is that it is very slow and doing `dat[dat.Trade_Id!=tib.Trade_Id]` does not work.

Someone have a better idea in order to be more computationally efficient? I have other databases like this one to work with and I would not like to be two days computing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter them out using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and negation operator `~`:

```
dat=dat[~dat['Trade_Id']isin(tib)]
```

[`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) will produce a boolean mask and you can invert this using `~` this will remove the rows that contain the id's

Example:

```
In [127]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(10)})
df

Out[127]:
   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9

In [128]:    
df[~df['col1'].isin([2,5,8])]

Out[128]:
   col1
0     0
1     1
3     3
4     4
6     6
7     7
9     9
```

The mask looks like this:

```
In [129]:
df['col1'].isin([2,5,8])

Out[129]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was sure there were some more efficient way but I wasn't able to find it. It works very fast.